# How to push file from pc to android device programmatically using ftp server/client

Tags: android, ftp, file-transfer

I'm new to android programming and ftp. Currently on a project to create android application to transfer file from PC to android device and verse vice. I'm able to transfer file from android device to PC using ftp server/client method. However, I'm facing difficulties on how to push file from PC to android device. Is it possible to push file from ftp server(PC) to client using ftp server/client? Or any alternatives to do so? Is there any tutorial/example which I could go through?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Transfer from android device to pc (android client side):

```
FTPClient mFTP = new FTPClient();
try {
    // Connect to FTP Server
    mFTP.connect("192.168.0.103");
    mFTP.login("user", "password");
    mFTP.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    mFTP.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    File file = new File(f);

    BufferedInputStream buffIn=null;
    buffIn=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    mFTP.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    mFTP.storeFile(filename, buffIn);
    buffIn.close();

    mFTP.logout();
    mFTP.disconnect();          
} catch (SocketException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Did you use any external library for this?